# Easiest way to use JSON.Net for both BSON and JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, bson

I have some pieces of data that are byte arrays `byte[]`, and I need to render them as base64 in JSON, but as raw byte arrays in BSON.

How can I easily do this in JSON.Net?

So, far I have something like so:

```
class Data
{
    public byte[] Bytes{get;set;}
}
```

Converting to BSON is fine, but when converting to JSON, it is of course not base64 encoded and treated as a string

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, using the following code with Json.Net 6.0.1, it appears to work just as you want with no special treatment: byte arrays are converted to base-64 strings and vice versa.  Are you serializing your objects in a different way, or using an old version?  If not, can you provide some code that demonstrates the problem?

```
string s = "Foo Bar Baz Quux";

Data data = new Data
{
    Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Console.WriteLine(json);

data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.Bytes));
```

Output:

```
{"Bytes":"Rm9vIEJhciBCYXogUXV1eA=="}
Foo Bar Baz Quux
```